# Passing configuration value to twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using symfony 4.0 and [created a custom config file](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html). I'm setting this config file values to a parameter, so that I can get them in a controller. But I want to pass/access them also to twig. How could I do this? Is is possible to assign the app config directly in config.yml or could I do it with a twig extension? I found `getGlobals()`, but this is deprecated. Still did it with a twig function, but seems not a good way to me.

Best and thank you!

AppExtension.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;


class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = $this->getConfiguration($configs, $container);
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        $container->setParameter('config', $config); 
    }

}

?>
```

Resources/config/app.yml:

```
app:
  document_access:
    payment:
        bank_details:
          account_owner: xxx
          iban: Iban
          bic: Bic
```

ConfigExtension.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class ConfigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getFunctions(){
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('config', array($this, 'getConfig')),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return $this->container->getParameter('config');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the variables required as environtment variables and parameters.

Then you can do it injecting the parameters into you controlller or registering the variables as twig globals.

**Controller**

```
class AngularController
{
    protected $twig;
    protected $accountOwner;
    protected $iban;
    protected $bic;

    /**
     * AngularController constructor.
     * @param $accountOwner
     * @param $iban
     * @param $bic
     */
    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, $accountOwner, $iban, $bic)
    {
        $this->twig=$twig;
        $this->accountOwner = $accountOwner;
        $this->iban = $iban;
        $this->bic = $bic;
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/uri", name="your_route")
     */
    public function yourActionAction()
    {
        $data=["account_owner"=>$this->accountOwner, "iban"=>$this->iban, "bic"=>$this->bic];
        $content=$this->twig->render('Bundle:Bundle:index.html.twig', $data);
        $response=new Response($content);
        return $response;
    }
}

controller.angular:
class: DJABundle\Controller\AngularController
arguments:
    - "@twig"
    - %bank_account_owner%
    - %bank_iban%
    - %bank_bic%
```

**Twig globals**

```
# app/config
twig:
    [...]
    globals:
        account_owner: %bank_account_owner%
        iban: %bank_iban%
        bic: "%bank_bic%"
```

**Usage in twig for both controller and globals**

```
Bank account owner: {{ account_owner }}
Bank account iban: {{ iban }}
Bank account bic: {{ bic }}
```

Comment: Thank you for that fast reply. I will try it like this.

Comment: Yes it works. But with this I have to set the variables I need in each controller respectively each action. Is it not possible to add them only once to have them in twig? As I did it with the TwigExtension/TwigFunction?

Comment: I added 2 options to achieve the same: Twig globals will make it available on all twig templates without needing to pass them

Comment: Sorry, but maybe I do not get it correctly. I have my parameters set in a separate config file (Resources/config/app.yml). But how could I set them to  twig globals? With "%bank_account_owser%" I only got the parameter, which is named like this. But my values are not set as parameter, but in the config file. I'm sorry for not understanding it correctly. Thank you!